# Why is $(X^{T}X+cI)^{-1} = (X^TX)^{-1}$ for ridge regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Why is $(X^{T}X+cI)^{-1} = (X^TX)^{-1}$? ($c$ is a scalar.)

My teacher in the lecture today used this fact when showing that the projection matrix of the ridge regression is idempotent.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a proof they could share or an explanation.
They wrote :
$$X(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T X (X^TX +\lambda I)^{-1}X^T = X(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T$$
I was wondering why $(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1} = (X^T X)^{-1}$ is true.

Edit:  Had a miss understanding of what mathematical facts she was using, so the question has changed dramatically.  Sorry guys I'm trying my best.

Comment: Does $A$ have any other special structure?

Comment: A in the example was $X^TX$.

Comment: This isn't generally true.  Perhaps there was more to the teacher's claim?  Assuming both matrices are invertible, $A$ and $A+cI$, their inverses are equal only if those two matrices are equal, i.e. if $c=0$.  So something seems missing from the problem statement.

Comment: This is not true in general or Tikhonov regularization would be useless, which it is not.

Comment: That isn't true. Consider e.g. the scalar case with $X=\lambda=1$. Your teacher probably was discussing the [limit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Limit_relations) of Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is wrong:
Just consider $X=I$ and $c=1$
You have
$$(X^TX+cI)^{-1}=(X^TX)^{-1}\\
(I^TI+1\cdot I)^{-1}=(I^T I)^{-1}\\
(I^2+ I)^{-1}=(I^2)^{-1}\\
(2I)^{-1}=I^{-1}\\
\frac{1}{2}I=I
$$
But this is false.
also the formula $(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}=(X^TX)^{-1}$ is wrong (you can always use the same example)

Comment: Why would this counter example be down voted?

Comment: I don't know ahaha, If you want you can upvote so I return to 0

Comment: @FabioCaiazzo I am very sorry I messed up the last part of the new equation.  I think the formula is $X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}$.  I tried on a few data sets and found that it was true but your logic makes a lot of sense so now I am just very confused.  I think will just email her.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Ah okok, don't worry

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of the inverse of an inversible matrix is the matrix itself so this equality can't be true unless $A + cI = A$ i.e. $c = 0$. Are you sure he wrote exactly that ?

Comment: The exact equation was $X(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T X (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T = X(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T$ (since the definition of idempotent is (a*a) = a).  While trying to figure this out I did do this empirically with some dataset and the property held for $X^TX$ for any c

Comment: @SlimeyGuy123 That is a very different equation and it does not imply that $(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1}=(X^T X)^{-1}$.

Comment: @SlimeyGuy123 This equation says that  if $P=X(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T$ then you have $P^2=P$, i.e. $P$ is idempotent and not what you have written in the question

Comment: @Fishbane could explain how?

Comment: @fotis Sorry I thought this must have been a general fact.  Will change the question.